# is it possible to use tr with the contents in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to encrypt a text, 
so I have this file encrypts a-z and A-z to different alphabet sets.

```
#!/bin/bashcode

encrypted=$1
message=$2

cat $message | tr "[a-z][A-Z]" "encrypted"
```

but this gives me weird set.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A [mcve] would do a lot of good here. "This is how I'm invoking the script, this is the output I get, and this is the output I expect" would be easier to test than merely discussing whether something is "weird". (If your output only contains characters from the word `encrypted`... well, that's exactly what one would expect from this code).

Comment: BTW, note that the meaning of `[a-z][A-Z]` is very locale-dependent, and if your code is run in a locale where collation order is like `AaBbCc...Zz` instead of like `ABC...Zabc...z` or `abc...zABC...Z`, you'll get surprising results.

Comment: (Or do you want `"$encrypted"`, to actually use the variable you assigned on the prior line? Or `"$(<"$encrypted")"`, to read the file named in that variable and substitute its contents? Without you showing us usage and the output you expect given that usage, we don't know what you *want* this code to do).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're looking for `< "$message" tr "[a-z][A-Z]" "$(cat "$encrypted")"`

Comment: But "encrypted" seems like the wrong name for your cipher.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Most `tr` don't require `[]` for ranges - notably GNU `tr` doesn't (https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Character-sets.html#Character-sets).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what do you mean by locale-dependent? I want to use the variable encrypted instead of just hardcoding what's in encrypted

Comment: @WilliamPursell I tried that but it gave me an error so I just moved on...maybe I typed something wrong

Comment: @lolads, what I mean by "locale-dependent" is that the meaning depends on your system's language settings. Different parts of the world have different rules about which letters sort before others, and expressions like `A-Z` follow those rules. If you want to make your code behave consistently everywhere, you'll spell out all the letters in the order you want them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ah that's true but when I googled around about tr it seems like [a-z][A-Z] is pretty common one. doesn't it mean, all the letters in a-z and the capital letters A-Z?

Comment: It's widely used in most of the English-speaking world, but there are still places where it breaks. This kind of widespread antipattern usage is an example of why trusting Google is sometimes unwise.

Comment: Exporting `LC_COLLATE=C` will help mitigate the effects by specifying a specific, known collation order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180077/discussion-between-lolads-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a one-to-one match of characters in `tr`:

```
cat $message | tr "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" "qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmMNBVCXZASDFGHJKLPOIUYTREWQ"
```

Comment: yeah that';s what I did but I don't think this is the most efficient way

Comment: `<"$message"` is going to be less buggy than `cat $message`. Even `cat "$message"` would be an improvement.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm using cat because I want to see the result on my terminal. isn't < redirecting output into a file?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I feel like I'm hardcoding?

Comment: @lolads, `<"$message" ...` sets up stdin for `...` to come straight from a file, whereas `cat "$message" | ...` sets up stdin for `...` to come from a copy of `cat` which is reading from a file, so you have a program (`cat`) sitting in between the file and the instance of `tr`. That kind of indirection means that the program (`...` in our example above) doesn't have direct access to the file -- it can't ask how long it is without reading all the way to the end to try to see, for example, because only `cat` has a handle on the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a secure encryption, but just for fun

```
$ function rot13() { tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m'; }

$ echo "Et tu, Brute?" | rot13
Rg gh, Oehgr?

$ echo "Et tu, Brute?" | rot13 | rot13
Et tu, Brute?
```

13 is obviously half of the alphabet length, therefore both encryption and decryption uses the same transformation; one kind of Ceaser cipher.